# Text content hidden behind PDF stamp after flattening form fields - iTextSharp, Adobe

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, adobe

If I don't flatten the form fields, the content appears over the stamp as expected. When I do flatten, the content is hidden behind the stamp. If I load the PDF into Adobe I can move the stamp and see the content behind it.

The PDF template was created in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (see bottom for version details). I fill in the document fields with conditional data using iTextSharp and return the PDF bytes.

[PDF Stamp, before move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD4rM.png)

[PDF Stamp, after move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0mr3.png)

```
// flatten fields
pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
```

```
// stamping
var fields = stamper.AcroFields;

stamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(fieldName, "textsize", fontSize, null);
fields.SetField(fieldName, value);
fields.SetFieldProperty(fieldName.ToString(),
    "setfflags",
    PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY,
    null);
```

iTextSharp 5.5.12

Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 20.6.20042.371103

Comment: Hi steve.

Please have a look at this article, to see how you can improve your answers
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Testing a counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why Is That Happening

When a PDF page is displayed, its static content is drawn first and all kinds of annotations are drawn thereafter on that static content. The annotations are drawn in the order in which they occur in the annotations array of the page.

Thus,

> If I don't flatten the form fields, the content appears over the stamp as expected.

Apparently you here mean the content of the form fields, not the static page content. Then this means simply that the stamp annotation occurs in the annotation array before the form field widget annotations.

> When I do flatten, the content is hidden behind the stamp.

As you only flatten the fields

> ```
> // flatten fields
> pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
> ```

this is natural: Flattening the fields means adding their contents to the static page content and removing the field from the form and the field widgets from the annotations. Thus, the former field content is now part of the static page content and, therefore, drawn before any remaining annotations, in particular before the stamp.

#### What To Do

If you want the field contents to appear over the stamp, you have two options:

- **Don't flatten the form fields** - If you don't flatten the form fields, their content remains in annotations which due to the order in the annotation array are drawn over the stamp

  To have a certain flattening-like effect you can set the form field *read-only* (as you already do) and their widget annotations *locked*.
- **Flatten the stamp first** - If you flatten the non-field annotations first, their contents are added to the static page contents first. Thus, if you thereafter flatten the fields, the field contents will appear over the stamp contents.

  iText has another property to ask for flattening non-field annotations:

  ```
  pdfStamper.AnnotationFlattening = true;
  ```

  Unfortunately it does not have a built-in feature to simply flatten all annotations (form field widgets and other annotations) in one go in the order in which they occur on the page. Even if you set both `FormFlattening` and `AnnotationFlattening` to `true`, the form field widgets are flattened before the other annotations.

  Thus, you'll have to stamp your PDF twice: In the first stamping step you set only `AnnotationFlattening` to `true` and in the second stamping set you set `FormFlattening` to `true`.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. I'm surprised I didn't come across annotation flattening before.

Comment: Great! If the answer solves your issue appropriately, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark at its upper left, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979/460854).

Comment: Getting a 'PDF startxref not found' exception. I am sorry to ask this of you, but if I put my code into another question, would you take a look at it and tell me what I did wrong? @mkl

Comment: @steve please also share an example result pdf in your question. An analysis of the broken result often more quickly points to the issue.

Comment: I figured it out. Just had to properly resolve the pdfReader and stamper, silly mistake by me. Thanks again for your help! @mkl

Comment: Testing a scrape